# novaprova unit test framework: no tests are detected

Tags: c, unit-testing

I have a simple test created and when I compile it with [*novaprova*](https://novaprova.org/), it does not discover tests.

The *novaprova* is actually built from scratch for my platform which is a **x86 Linux**  custom platform.

Has anybody seen similar issues?

The following is the debug enabled output of the *novaprova* test i have.

```
./testrunner
np: creating testmanager_t instance
np: NovaProva Copyright (c) Gregory Banks
np: Built for O/S linux architecture x86
np: adding classifier /^test_([a-z0-9].*)/ -> test
...
...
np: adding classifier /^__np_parameter_(.*)/ -> param
np: creating np::spiegel::dwarf::state_t instance
np: state_t::add_self: platform linkobj (null)
np: state_t::add_self: platform linkobj /usr/lib/gcc/i486-pc-linux-gnu/4.1.2/libstdc++.so.6
np: state_t::add_self: platform linkobj /usr/i486-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libbfd-2.18.so
np: state_t::add_self: have spiegel linkobj
np: state_t::add_self: platform linkobj /lib/libdl.so.2
np: state_t::add_self: platform linkobj /lib/librt.so.1
np: state_t::add_self: platform linkobj /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2
np: state_t::add_self: platform linkobj /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
np: state_t::add_self: platform linkobj /lib/libpthread.so.0
np: state_t::add_self: platform linkobj /lib/libz.so.1
np: state_t::add_self: platform linkobj /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
np: state_t::add_self: platform linkobj /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4
np: state_t::add_self: platform linkobj /lib/libm.so.6
np: state_t::add_self: platform linkobj /usr/lib/gcc/i486-pc-linux-gnu/4.1.2/libgcc_s.so.1
np: state_t::add_self: platform linkobj /lib/libc.so.6
np: state_t::add_self: platform linkobj /lib/ld-linux.so.2
np: state_t::add_self: platform linkobj /usr/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8
np: opening bfd /usr/i486-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libbfd-2.18.so
np: sections:
np: section name .hash size 1ce0 filepos 114 index -1
np: section name .gnu.hash size 1ca0 filepos 1df4 index -1
np: section name .dynsym size 33d0 filepos 3a94 index -1
np: section name .dynstr size 4823 filepos 6e64 index -1
np: section name .gnu.version size 67a filepos b688 index -1
np: section name .gnu.version_r size 50 filepos bd04 index -1
np: section name .rel.dyn size 8010 filepos bd54 index -1
np: section name .rel.plt size d60 filepos 13d64 index -1
np: section name .init size 17 filepos 14ac4 index -1
np: section name .plt size 1ad0 filepos 14adc index 9
np: found system mapping for section .plt
np: section name .text size 89474 filepos 165b0 index -1
np: section name .fini size 1c filepos 9fa24 index -1
np: section name .rodata size 10c7b filepos 9fa40 index -1
np: section name .eh_frame_hdr size 1c filepos b06bc index -1
np: section name .eh_frame size 5c filepos b06d8 index -1
np: section name .ctors size 8 filepos b0fa8 index -1
np: section name .dtors size 8 filepos b0fb0 index -1
np: section name .jcr size 4 filepos b0fb8 index -1
np: section name .data.rel.ro size 6e60 filepos b0fc0 index -1
np: section name .dynamic size d0 filepos b7e20 index -1
np: section name .got size f0 filepos b7ef0 index -1
np: section name .got.plt size 6bc filepos b7ff4 index -1
np: section name .data size fc0 filepos b86c0 index -1
np: section name .bss size 41f0 filepos b9680 index -1
np: debug sections map:
np: index 0 name .debug_aranges map 0x0 size 0x0
np: index 1 name .debug_pubnames map 0x0 size 0x0
np: index 2 name .debug_info map 0x0 size 0x0
np: index 3 name .debug_abbrev map 0x0 size 0x0
np: index 4 name .debug_line map 0x0 size 0x0
np: index 5 name .debug_frame map 0x0 size 0x0
np: index 6 name .debug_str map 0x0 size 0x0
np: index 7 name .debug_loc map 0x0 size 0x0
np: index 8 name .debug_ranges map 0x0 size 0x0
np: index 9 name .plt map 0x55678adc size 0x1ad0
np: reading compile units for linkobj /usr/i486-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libbfd-2.18.so
np: DWARF compile unit header at section offset 0x0
np: scanning for test functions
np: WARNING: no tests discovered
np: running
np: 0 run 0 failed
```

Comment: Seeing as my answer is the only one to this question, please consider up-voting it or selecting it as the correct answer to this question. Thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the novaprova framework and your issue, I have arrived to the following documentation: [Writing Test Functions](http://novaprova.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html).

To quote from the 'The Test Tree' section:

> The Test Tree
>
> Most other test frameworks provide a simple, 2-level mechanism for organizing tests; tests are grouped into suites.
>
> By contrast NovaProva organizes tests into an tree of test nodes. All
>   the tests built into a test executable are gathered at runtime and are
>   fitted into a tree, with a single common root. The root is then pruned
>   until the test names are as short as possible. Each test function is a
>   leaf node in this tree (usually).
>
> The locations of tests in this tree are derived from the names of the
>   test function, the basename of the test source file containing the
>   test function, and the hierarchy of filesystem directories containing
>   that source file. These form a natural classifying scheme that you are
>   already controlling by choosing the names of filenames and functions.
>   These names are stuck together in order from least to most specific,
>   separated by ASCII ‘.’ characters, and in general look like this.

```
dir.subdir.more.subdirs.filename.function
```

Here’s an example showing how test node names fall naturally out of your test code organization.

```
% cat tests/startrek/tng/federation/enterprise.c 
static void test_torpedoes(void) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Testing photon torpedoes\n"); }

% cat tests/startrek/tng/klingons/neghvar.c 
static void test_disruptors(void) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Testing disruptors\n"); }

% cat tests/starwars/episode4/rebels/xwing.c 
static void test_lasers(void) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Testing laser cannon\n"); }

% ./testrunner --list 
tests.startrek.tng.federation.enterprise.torpedoes
tests.startrek.tng.klingons.neghvar.disruptors
tests.starwars.episode4.rebels.xwing.lasers
```

Note that for each recognized test via provanove, the following function signature is being used:

```
static void test_[your tested function name](void) {
```

Based on your question - this seems like a likely culprit causing your issues.

Comment: No, the tests are working good in another platform which x86_64. The platform on which i see the issue is a gentoo based one and also has old libc,glibc libraries. So I am suspecting novaprova is in able to do some if it tricks using the old versions of the gnublibs.

Comment: @AbhayadevS : Perhaps the other platform has a better pathing configuration? So that the tests are found in the expected directory?
I feel like it is a pathing issue..... Perhaps this is the important line in your output: `np: adding classifier /^test_([a-z0-9].*)/ -> test`